# Graph on the cover of Bollobás's "Combinatorics"

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

I was browsing the library and I found Bela Bollobás book "Combinatorics: Set Systems, Hypergraphs, Families of Vectors and Probabilistic Combinatorics" and, on its cover, it has a graph that I don't quite recognize:

[image: Graph from the cover]

Is this graph any "interesting", as used for counterexamples (e.g., Petersen's Graph)? I could determine some of its characteristics (9 vertices, regular of valency 4, non-planar, diameter 2 etc.), but is it distinguished in any way for being featured in an important book?

Comment: It possesses a certain kind of regularity: If $x,y$ are neighbors, there is always $1$ path of length $2$ between them, while if they are not neighbors, there is always $2$ paths of length two between them. I forget what this sort of regularity is called, however.

Comment: Ah, the term I was thinking of is "strongly regular." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Great. Translating from your description to wikipedia's notation: for any two adjacent vertices, there is exactly 1 path of length 1 between then, which means that any 2 adjacent vertices have exactly 1 neighbor in common (in wikipedia's notation, $\lambda = 1$). For any 2 non-adjacent vertices, there is exactly 2 (vertex disjoint) paths of length 2 between them, which means that 2 non-adjacent vertices have 2 neighbors in common (in wikipedia's notation, $\mu = 2$). The graph is regular of degree $k = 4$ with $v = 9$ vertices and is, therefore, $sgr(9, 4, 1, 2)$.

Comment: BTW, all of the answers are superb and I don't know what to choose as "the" answer to this question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This graph is known as the generalized quadrangle (2,1), it is also the line graph of the $K_{3,3}$, as well as the Paley-9 graph. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedQuadrangle.html) for more information. I am not aware that it is used as a prominent counterexample.

Answer (score 8):

It's isomorphic to the rook graph on a 3 by 3 grid:

[image: Rook graph on a 3 by 3 grid]

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph) lists some nice properties of square rook graphs. For example, the graph is perfect, completely symmetric (i.e. looks the same from every vertex), it's the line graph of $K_{3,3}$, ...

Answer (score 4):

It's also the Cartesian product of a 3-cycle with another 3-cycle.

Answer (score 2):

It's the unit distance embedding of $K_3 \times K_3$, one of the few strongly regular graphs that has a unit distance embedding in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is also known as $3 \times 3$ rook graph (though sometimes mistakenly as $3 \times 3$ grid graph). It also is a generalized quadrangle as pointed out above by A. Schulz.